Parallel Processing with Intermediate Serial Combined Result
I some code running in a few worker threads spawned by the main thread. I have another task that depends on  part of the results from these parallel tasks, but does not depend on these other tasks completely finishing. Those other tasks have later computations that depend on this joint computation (but don't strictly need to be run in the same thread). Is there a way to achieve this sort of flow using something like the rangeless library or the STL, or another simple library?
Sketching it out:
MAIN THREAD: 
    Spawns Others
    -> Joint Calculation J on Results of A 
    -> Later Joint Calculation L on Results of B & C
OTHER THREADS
   1: A -> B -> C on results of J
   2: A -> B -> C on results of J
   3: A -> B -> C on results of J
   4: A -> B -> C on results of J

Obviously I could just break it into multiple sections A(parallel) -> J(serial) -> B&C(Parallel), but B could be done in parallel with J instead, and then the other worker threads can be kept doing work at the same time.

If you want results from other threads when they finish have a look at std::async/std::future. Other buildling blocks are : std::mutex/std::scoped_lock/std::condition_variable and/or std::latch, std::barrier. You are the only one really knowing your synchronization points so you will have to figure out which ones to use where

OpenMP has such features: you can spawn thread with #pragma omp parallel, execute work only on the master thread with #pragma omp master or one thread (any) with #pragma omp single. You can do global synchronization with #pragma omp barrier. An alternative solution is to use dependent OpenMP tasks: you can spawn tasks so that they are executed in multiple threads and then create a task dependent of the previous one with #pragma omp task depend(...). Yet another solution is to create recursive tasks: 1 thread create a task creating N tasks, then doing #pragma omp taskwait.

There is a catch though: recursive tasks and dependencies generally does not mix well (you can only define local dependencies) so you need to choose one approach. It also does not mix well with manual (or library) C++ approach (like most libraries anyway). (Re-)Implementing (efficient) dependent tasks manually in C++ tends to be difficult.
